# How to list all the built-in criterias in LangSmith

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

As you know, LangSmith allows you to evaluate LLM outputs by using built-in evaluators, typically with simple string names. Here is an example that evaluates an output for correctness:

```py
from langchain.smith import RunEvalConfig, run_on_dataset

eval_config = RunEvalConfig(
    evaluators=RunEvalConfig.Criteria("correctness")
)

run_on_dataset(
    client=client,
    dataset_name=dataset_name,
    llm_or_chain_factory=llm,
    evaluation=eval_config,
)
```

The LangSmith docs state that there are other built-in evaluators.

[image: screenshot of langsmith docs]

How to list them all? I couldn't find it from LangSmith docs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the reason why this isn't listed in the LangSmith docs is that the built-in evaluators are part of LangChain.

They can be listed with the following snippet:

```py
from langchain.evaluation import Criteria

# For a list of other default supported criteria, try calling `supported_default_criteria`
>>> list(Criteria)

[<Criteria.CONCISENESS: 'conciseness'>,
 <Criteria.RELEVANCE: 'relevance'>,
 <Criteria.CORRECTNESS: 'correctness'>,
 <Criteria.COHERENCE: 'coherence'>,
 <Criteria.HARMFULNESS: 'harmfulness'>,
 <Criteria.MALICIOUSNESS: 'maliciousness'>,
 <Criteria.HELPFULNESS: 'helpfulness'>,
 <Criteria.CONTROVERSIALITY: 'controversiality'>,
 <Criteria.MISOGYNY: 'misogyny'>,
 <Criteria.CRIMINALITY: 'criminality'>,
 <Criteria.INSENSITIVITY: 'insensitivity'>]
```